# ffmpeg input/output error when using mac system temp file path

Tags: macos, command-line, ffmpeg, video

I've got an `ffmpeg` command that is *supposed* to output a thumbnail for a given video at a resolution of `[W]x720`.

The input videos are uploaded and stored temporarily in the `/var/folders` directory on **OS X**, along with the output path, which is generated by a library. So, the final command ends up looking similar to the following:

```
ffmpeg -ss 14.118271 -i /var/folders/__/INPUT/T/INPUT/INPUT -y -filter_complex scale=w=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:h=720[size0];[size0]split=1[screen0] -vframes 1 -map [screen0] var/folders/__/OUTPUT/T/OUTPUT.jpg
```

The command works perfectly when used with a non-temporary file path, so I'm not entirely sure why it's not working here. This is the error I'm encountering:

```
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=7.8 size=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.153x    
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=7.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.141x    
video:119kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

I've made another post about this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305398/ffmpeg-fails-when-using-a-temporary-file-path-for-output) with the more programmatic details about how I'm generating the temporary file paths.

Comment: I don't know if it is the problem, but your output path misses the leading `/`